# Moving files between drives in PHP? (Linux)

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos7

I have a simple website where I've got file hosting setup. It's running on a laptop which doesn't have much space, So I bought 2 external hard disks.

I have them mounted in `/opt/oweb/html/Downloads/Files` and `/opt/oweb/html/Downloads/Uploads`. Files uploaded to PHP go into `/tmp`, this worked fine when it was just the laptop's internal drive. But now with the two additional drives PHP presents this error:

`Warning: move_uploaded_file(Uploads/Guy Laughing in The Dark Meme Live Wallpaper.mp4): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/oweb/html/Downloads/Upload.php on line 40`
`Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpUY0tO8' to 'Uploads/Guy Laughing in The Dark Meme Live Wallpaper.mp4' in /opt/oweb/html/Downloads/Upload.php on line 40`

The apache user has all the necessary permissions, so it must be because the directories are on separate partitions (drives). How do I remedy this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I partitioned the 2 drives on windows, because cfdisk wasn't working for whatever reason. I tested by logging in as apache, then creating and deleting files. It worked. However, PHP is now saying that it can't open a file, so I presume it's a problem with PHP, not anything else.

Comment: I am not aware of such a limitation connected to different partitions. Where should that come from?

Comment: Are you really sure that the apache process has access to _all_ folders in the path to that folder?

Comment: Please add to the question the information how you mounted those partitions into your system.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix the problem. When I was initially setting up apache, I had problems with `SELinux`, I remembered that and decided to try it.

For some reason, even though the partitions are mounted in a subdirectory of the server, they have a different security configuration. So I just copied the configuration from the server root directory onto each of the mounting directories and sure enough, it worked.